# How to generate combinations of values from two subarrays?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, combinations, cartesian-product

I'm have two subarrays like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [name] => Color
            [value] => White,Black
            [attribute_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [name] => Size
            [value] => L,S,M,XL,XXL,XXXL
            [attribute_id] => 5
        )

)
```

I want to generate combinations of the value elements' data.

Expected result:

```
White L
White S
White M
White XL
White XXL
White XXXL
Black L
Black S
Black M
Black XL
Black XXL
Black XXXL
```

I've tried with foreach, but not able to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "combination of value field"? You want to have more then one value? Use the array then.

Comment: What is the difference to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28623784/3933332 ?

Comment: This is called "cartesian product" - look it up.

Comment: Iterate (foreach) trough first level to process all items. Then, inside that loop explode value field by comma to get array of values. Then iterate trough that array and for each member add new member in some third array which will contain the results. At least try codding - don't expect just to say what you need and to get code written by somebody else.

Comment: You have tried twice to get someone else to code this for you. Make some sort of attempt yourself and people will help, **but we dont produce code from specifications**

Comment: An arrays are programming basics and are "must to know". If you will not try to do it yourself - you will not study programming. Use foreach loop and another hint for you - use explode().

Comment: Given answer to your question

Comment: @RiggsFolly Apparently, we do!

Comment: @Strawberry So we do. Well you got to love us really dont you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `explode()`. Use the code below:

```
<?php
// Your array:
$array = array(array("id"=>17,"name" => "Color","value" => "White,Black","attribute_id" => 1),array("id" => 15,"name" => "Size","value" => "L,S,M,XL,XXL,XXXL", "attribute_id" => 5));

$x = explode(",",$array[0]["value"]);
foreach($x as $p=>$k){

    $explode = explode(",",$array[1]["value"]);
    foreach($explode as $pe){
        echo $k." ".$pe."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```